# How to check how many characters there are in my string?

Tags: string

Lets say I have a simple string:

```
{% set string = "Simple String" %}
```

How to get number of characters of my string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Twig has a [length filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html) that can help you with that:

```
{% set stringLength = "Simple String" | length %}
```

Note that this also works on arrays to give you the number of items in the array.

Answer (score 2):

If you are attempting to get a count of the string, you can use Twigs dump function.

{{ dump(myString) }}

Comment: This only works in devMode from what I've read. Never tried it outside of devMode, though.